# Android code : How to use YOUTUBE OFFLINE functionality for .mp3 files?

Tags: android, android-studio, mp3

I am developing an android application for Online Music streaming. I want to download MP3 files from the server and play that file when the user is offline. And the downloaded file can only be played through applicaion

please give your best solution

Comment: Use DRM protection, it's the same that saavn uses! I have not tried to implement it in a code but I suppose that will do the trick for you

Comment: Thank u.. Can u tell me how to use the DRM protection .  Any links..?

Comment: _"..I want to download MP3 files from the server and play that file when the user is offline"_ so do you have a link to example mp3 file? Do you have code that you've tried for saving example file to device or sd card storage? What can we help you with exactly since there is no code shown... Are you asking us to google **Android download online file to local storage** for you and give you links to the Android manual? Best solution is you trying some file save tutorials. If you have code issue then ask on this programming Q&A site + **show a sample of your problem code**